# MenuItem.Icon VS 2015 hidden in Windows 10

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2015

I'm in charge of maintaining an application developed in VS 2015. The application looks great in Windows 7, but when run in Windows 10 the MenuItem.Icons shift down and to the right, so that only the top left corners show.

[Windows 7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggf18.png)

[Windows 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3AdO.png)

I've been playing with the padding and margins in xaml, but I'd like to figure out what is happening instead of just creating a work-around.

I'm new to Visual Studio. Maybe this will be obvious?

```
<Menu Name="MainMenu" Margin="0,128,0,12" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="172">
<MenuItem Header="Search" FontFamily="Shruti" FontSize="26" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Click="Search_Click" Cursor="Hand" x:Name="SearchMenu" IsTabStop="false" Height="55" Width="162" >
<MenuItem.Icon>
<Image Width="50" Height="50" Cursor="Hand" IsManipulationEnabled="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,0,0" >
<Image.Style>
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
<Setter Property="Source" Value="/DomesticPartnership;component/Images/Search-Icon.gif"/>
<Style.Triggers>
<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
<Setter Property="Source" Value="/DomesticPartnership;component/Images/Search-Icon.png"/>
</Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
</Style>
</Image.Style>
</Image>
</MenuItem.Icon>
</MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

Comment: Are both systems running on the same screen with the same screen resolution ?

Comment: I'm running them on the same screen - but I'm using a Remote Desktop for the Windows 10 version.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else runs into trouble with their icons in Win10:

I played with the margins and padding until I got the icons to show.
It's not pretty, but the icons show in Win10 now.

Thanks!

Comment: You should probably wrap your image in a ViewBox so you can save your Margins

Comment: You know, I forgot to include the ViewBox in the code sample. That just might be part of the problem. Thanks!